# How to get all Note Board notes?

Tags: timer-jobs, social-note

I have written code like this

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1000/");
var socialCommentManager = new SocialCommentManager(context);

// Get last 24 hrs notes
TimeSpan tInterval = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
DateTime tSchedule = DateTime.Now - tInterval;

SocialComment[] allComments = socialCommentManager.GetComments(uri, 100, 0, tSchedule);

 foreach (SocialComment comment in allComments)
                {
// Print statement goes here
}
```

When I excute the code it returns only the home page notes not on other page or library. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API, it appears that SocialCommentManager.GetComments() methods only support getting all comments either by a particular user or a specific URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialcommentmanager_methods

It appears that you would have to iterate through either the users or the URLs you would like to retrieve the comments for.